# Crossfilter for multiple columns?

Tags: javascript, crossfilter

I have data for regions and years:

```
region  year   value
A       1900   60
A       1901   70
B       1900   78
B       1901   90
```

Is it correct to set up a crossfilter for both region and year like this?

```
myFilter = crossfilter(data)

byRegionAndYear = myFilter.dimension(function(d){
      return d.region + d.year
})
```

And how do I get the results of a filtering query? (now I use top(xxx))

byRegionAndYear.filterExact("A1970").top(100);

Comment: Check out this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10608171/using-crossfilter-to-dynamically-return-results-in-javascript/10660123#10660123) and let me know if it helps.  The preview to that answer is that I would create two separate dimensions and filter on both then get the top. If you have more questions after reviewing the example though just let me know.

Comment: Thanks @slojo, seems to make sense! Any idea on how to interpolate values using crossfilter? Suppose I have a year (1950) and want to find the neighboring years that have data (I.e. 1948 and 1953) and return the interpolated value for another dimension. Can I do this?

Comment: woops messed up trying to respond on mobile.  The short answer is depending on the end goal I am inclined to approach this problem from another angle.  Crossfilter to my knowledge does not have this funcitonality out of the box although it could help you find the two nearest points where you could then using the two values interpolate.  Another approach would be to consider modeling your data on its own and creating a function to estimate the missing values.  Simple case for instance could be linear regresssion.  Maybe close this one out and start a new question? I'd be happy to help more.

Comment: Thank you @slojo. Yes, I should probably interpolate the data beforehand instead.